# default_node_config is ignored when new nodes are created

Tags: ejabberd

I have a fairly standard ejabberd install backed by MySQL and I want to pre-configure the PubSub nodes to set `send_last_published_item` to `never` or `on_sub`. Currently, I have users who can be subscribed to as many as 50 PubSub nodes which flood the client after logging in and I want to dial that down a bit as I am expecting that number to go up significantly in the future.

I updated ejabberd.yml and set a few values in `default_node_config`  and then I created a new node via

```
<iq type='set' id='some-id'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <create node='123'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

However, when I checked the database, the new node ignored all defaults from `default_node_config`. This node has not been modified by someone else, it is created entirely anew with a configuration that ignores the defaults:

```
SELECT * FROM `pubsub_node_option` WHERE nodeid=9;

nodeid  name  val 
9 access_model  presence  
9 deliver_notifications true  
9 deliver_payloads  true  
9 itemreply none  
9 max_items 1 
9 max_payload_size  250000  
9 notification_type headline  
9 notify_config false 
9 notify_delete false 
9 notify_retract  false 
9 persist_items true  
9 presence_based_delivery true  
9 publish_model publishers  
9 purge_offline false 
9 roster_groups_allowed []  
9 rsm true  
9 send_last_published_item  on_sub_and_presence 
9 sql true  
9 subscribe true
```

These values are suspiciously similar to the defaults from [`ejabberd/src/node_flat.erl`](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/node_flat.erl#L76).

This is what the configuration looks like:

```yaml
  mod_pubsub:
    db_type: sql
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
    default_node_config:
      send_last_published_item: never
      notification_type: normal
      notify_retract: false
      max_items: 4
      delivers_notifications: false
      notify_delete: true
      max_payload_size: 100
```

I've read the documentation so many times and the description for `default_node_config` is confusing to me:

> default_node_config
>
> To override default node configuration, regardless of node plugin. Value is a list of key-value definition. Node configuration still uses default configuration defined by node plugin, and overrides any items by value defined in this configurable list.

I read this as *[This is to be used] to override default node configuration, regardless of node plugin*. But then it says that the *Node configuration still uses default configuration defined by the node plugin, and overrides any items by value defined in this configurable list*.

This can be interpreted as `default_node_config` having precedence, but the second sentence is weird to me.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Is there a way to configure the defaults for the node plugin? I am using the "flat" type for nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: In a very quick read, this seems a bug. Otherwise, the documentation should be rephrased to be more clear. I see you crossposted this in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/4070 Can you add the additional information from this post to t hat page (it probably helps to investigate the problem)?

Comment: Sure thing, I just did. For the moment I'm just updating my clients to publish in the correct configuration and ran a database query to update existing nodes.